# How to specify multiple hosts in the manifest of an OSGI fragment bundle in apache karaf

Tags: java, osgi, apache-karaf, osgi-fragment

According to the OSGI specification, a fragment bundle in OSGI can have multiple hosts. But in apache karaf it does not seem to work.

I have tried the following.

```
Fragment-Host: default_host;bundle-version=1.0.0,Second_host;bundle-version=1.0.0
```

Comment: What do you mean "is not working"? Do you receive some sorts of error?

Comment: there is no error but there is some unpredictable behaviour as only one host bundle is available in the console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right that a fragment can have multiple hosts according to the specification. But it seems to be limited to different versions of bundles with the same symbolic name:

The grammar for [`Fragment-Host`](https://docs.osgi.org/specification/osgi.core/8.0.0/framework.module.html#framework.module.fragmenthost) is defined as

> ```
> Fragment-Host       ::= bundle-description
> bundle-description  ::= symbolic-name ( ';' parameter )*
> ```

and by using a version range, you technically define multiple host:

> bundle-version - The version range to select the host bundle. If a range is used, then the fragment can attach to multiple hosts.

It doesn't seem to be possible to attach a fragment to host bundles with different names like in your example.